# How to make a dynamic wordpress page (custom control/page template box)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, templates, themes

I have completed numerous wordpress template tutorials focusing on implementing multiple pages, and a custom dynamic navigation. The only issue I have is finding a source on creating a custom template box. For example, my goal is to customize the page template box following the mock up. The content placement is done in php, and designed in css. That way I dont have to add content in php but instead add it in wordpress based on my custom design. I have not found any source to achieve this. Does anyone have a source that displays how to create custom template boxes(the dynamic part)?

**Links below is what I used to create my wordpress site**
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/migrate-existing-website-to-wordpress/

[custom navbar for wordpress using bootstrap](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

I tried another source called **Dynamic Page Templates in WordPress, Part 2** which suppose to explain how to create custom controls/template boxes. Following the link was unclear, resulting in not achieving the goal.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to create a dynamic page in WordPress. I am sharing one of it. Install Advanced Custom Field Plugin and read its documentation. It allows page content to be changed from back-end (Its great for text/images). For areas where you want to user to choose whatever custom widget she wants to choose, add a widget area following any custom widget tutorial.